# Flyway.migrate not working in idea

Tags: intellij-idea, flyway

Alright, so I'm using Idea right, and I'm getting this exception: Exception in thread "main" org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration while attempting to run my project in it.

It's not a code error, as far as I can tell as this project worked fine before and hasn't been touched until now. Heck, it still runs fine now in a jar file. (Source Code:
21:50:17 http://github.com/TechCavern/WaveTact).

All I have done is run "gradle idea", and then try to run the project as an application in idea.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understood the problem, but you are using command line to execute Flyway?

Comment: Oh my bad. I forgot about this. But the issue has beem resolved. Turns out ths project needed to be imported as a gradle project in idea FIRST, then gradle idea is run. And no, I wasn't using command line to execute flyway when getting that exception, that exception occured when I was trying to run the project in idea, the application executing flyway